# Vue - Property 'distanceRange' does not exist on type '{ updateFilters(filters: any): void; }'

Tags: vue.js

I want to use the parameter of a function and store them as a variable, but the erro fom the title shows up. I already looked the prolem up, but nothing helps.

HTML:

```
<ion-content :fullscreen="true" class="main-wrapper">
  <div id="map" style="height: 100%; "></div>
  <MapSidebar class="map-sidebar" @filters="(filters:any) => this.updateFilters(filters)"/>
</ion-content>
```

Vue:

```
data() {
  return {
    distanceRange: 0,
  };
},
...
methods: {
  updateFilters(filters:any) {
    this.distanceRange = filters.distanceRange
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding console.log to the things you are calling `distanceRange` on. It might help you understand the error or give more info to this question